# Ajax request not printing html response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an `ajax` request that fetches some data and returns a `html` response that I print out on the page. The problem is that for some reason the `html` response doesn't get printed, only textual data does. The correct response is being returned as I've checked in the browser console.

Here is the `ajax` function:

```
function getRating(work_id, selectorToWriteTo)
{
     $.ajax({
        url: '/read/getRatingsForGivenWork',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        data: { field1: work_id},
        success: function (data) {
            //your success code
            $(selectorToWriteTo).html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Error: " + thrownError);
        }
     });
}
```

function that returns the html data:

```
public function getRatingsForGivenWork()
{
     $ratings = $this->getModel ( 'read', 'getRatingsForGivenWork', $_GET['field1']);
     if($ratings !== null)
     {      
          print "<div class=\"ui small star rating\" data-rating=\"" . $ratings ."\" data-max-rating=\"5\">Leave rating</div>";
     }
     else
     {
          print 0;
     }

   }
```

Where I invoke the ajax function:

```
<div class="extra">
     <script>
          document.write(getRating(<?php echo $row['works.work_id']; ?>, '.extra'));
     </script>    
</div>
```

Response in Chrome developer tools:

[image]

Chrome console:

[image]

The right response comes back but it doesn't print the html on the page. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Actually, I don't think it solves you problem, but you are overriding your JavaScript code, because it's in the `div`. And can you show us what in in the Chrome console, please ?

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot of the Chrome console response

Comment: This in not the console you are showing... you are showing a screenshot of Network > Response. I need the console screen.

Comment: @Seblor Ah my bad! I have included the console screenshot now.

Comment: Try removing the `<script>...</script>` from the `div`.

Comment: @Seblor I can't because then I would be writing javascript in HTML code :/

Comment: But... this is exactly the way JavaScript should be implemented. You can put it anywhere in your html script.

Comment: @Seblor I don't think you understand the way embedded javascript works, you need `<script>...</script>`, tags so that the javascript code gets interpreted as javascript otherwise it would treat it is plain text.

Comment: @user3574492 could you provide the css for the following classes: `ui small star rating`? Thanks!

Comment: I never said deleting the script tags. I told you to moved them out of the div.

Comment: @Seblor Moving the script tags out of the div has no effect whatsoever, does the same thing but in a different place

Comment: With the script inside the div, you delete it while it execute. `.html ()` delete all the div content and refill it. So you are deleting the executed script.

Comment: Yes, that was suggested already and I have tried to move the script out of the div but it prints `undefined`

Comment: What if you put some text in the `div` ? Is it deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep into this I managed to figure out the problem. It all came down to the fact that PHP is loaded before JavaScript.

In my PHP loop I was printing out each item in a database table. For each item I was calling the ajax function `getRating(work_id, selectorToWriteTo)` so that it prints out the rating.

The result of the ajax function is outputting the following element:

```
<div class="ui small star rating" data-rating="3" data-max-rating="5">Leave rating</div>
```

This element requires a javascript initialization for it to work and appear correctly. I had the initialization wrapped in a document.ready() like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.ui.small.rating').rating();
});
```

This means that the star rating obviously only gets initialized once the document is ready and fully loaded, which in my case was after the PHP code was executed, so the PHP was outputting the element before it was initialized and this is why nothing was showing.

One way around this was by using JavaScripts `window.onload` event so that the rating gets initialized when the page is fully loaded:

```
window.onload = function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(true);
    $('.ui.small.rating').rating();
}
```

This now outputs the element, not quite sure why though as I'd have to look at the `onload` event a lot more in depth.
There is still some unusual behaviour, on most of the items the element gets printed fine, however when I reload the page again a few times it is missing from a few items, completely random behaviour.

Thanks everyone for the help.

**UPDATE:**

I recent;y found a more robust, quicker solution to this. I simply had to wrap the initialization in a [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function:

```
window.onload = function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
       event.stopPropagation(true);
       $('.ui.small.rating').rating('disable');
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting id to the HTML `div` and then pass it as selector; and keep function call outside of the `div`.

```
<div class="extra" id="div1">
</div>

<script>
    getRating(<?php echo $row['works.work_id']; ?>, '#div1');
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the result, the output is still not getting printed

Comment: Assign `data` in `success` event of Ajax request to a local variable and then use simple javascript to assign that variable to div's `innerHTML` property. Also make sure `div` is not enclosed between any other html tags such as `PRE`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see if your AJAX request is returning any data at all?
Try opening the Inspect Element window and go to Network.

Try to send your request and see what's there in response.

Also, what are you sending to function `getRating(work_id, selectorToWriteTo)`?

What does `selectorWriteTo` contain?

Comment: It returns the right data as seen from Chrome's developer tools in the response tab as shown in the screenshot above, the `getRating()` is called like this:  `document.write(getRating(<?php echo $row['works.work_id']; ?>, '.extra'));` where `.extra` is the name of the class of the element for which to output the html data

Comment: Can you confirm if you have mutliple `'.extra'` elements? Are they hidden by default?
Can you try saying `alert(data)` first?

Comment: I can confirm that there are not multiple `.extra` elements and when I alert the data it alerts exactly the same as the response. Only doesn't print on page.

Comment: Can you create a `<div id="test"></div>` and use "#test" instead of ".extra"?
I'm also wondering why you're calling this method inside a `document.write` as it would yield no benefit.

Comment: Just created a `<div id="test"></div>` and used `#test`, does exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try using. Load is used to load the html content and display it as a part of your page. May be this will help you.

```
 $(selectorToWriteTo).load(data);
```

Comment: This also prints undefined, why is it printing undefined when the response that is being returned is perfectly fine html?

Comment: can i ask how are you passing the selector? is it just the class or ID name or your passing entire selector as .selector or #selector???

Comment: I am passing the class name like this: `document.write(getRating(<?php echo $row['works.work_id']; ?>, '.extra'));`  the `.extra` bit is the selector, note the comma `,` that separates the parameters

Comment: i am suspecting the .extra you are passing as selector needs to wrapped in the quotes and also check if that the selector is present on the DOM, i know you said it is available, but just confirm it using if($('some_element').length == 0) { alert("Not Present");
}

Comment: Yes, just tested that with  `if($('.extra').length == 0) { alert("Not Present"); } else { alert("present");` and it alerts present

Comment: good so just wrap like this $("'"+selectorToWriteTo+"'").load(data); and should work. if load deosnt work try using .html as mentioned by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80102/discussion-between-chetank-and-user3574492).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a racecondition problem here, there are some changes i'm goint to suggest in order to tackle down the issue, first, I see you are looping maybe a response from an SQL call?, so, you are firing your js code once per iteration, and you always replace the html of your `.extra` div, which means that you are removing the script tag from there (should not be a real issue since php code gets executed before the JS) But i suggest the following:

First, move the script:

```
<div class="extra"></div>
<script>
    document.write(getRating(<?php echo $row['works.work_id']; ?>, '.extra'));
</script>
```

And I suggest you move the `<div class="extra"></div>` outside the PHP loop (if its inside of it, otherwise its ok) so you only get one div. And leave the script tag inside the loop.
Now, you are replacing the whole `.extra` html each time your ajax request is succesfull, so maybe the last occurrence of the loop ends up in your else statement and thus `print 0;`. I also recommend that you print something else instead of 0, like `<span>You cannot rate this</span>` that way you will notice whats going on.
Now, in order to not replace the entire divs html, use append instead:

```
$(selectorToWriteTo).append(data);
```

Another thing to check is the CSS for the classes `ui small star rating extra` and validate that they are being displayed, and not `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but it's actually not an issue to do with race conditions and what gets rendered first, it's actually a lot simpler than that. The elements are printing out in a loop just fine, if in my server side code I print a simple `<p>Rate me</p>` then it prints on the page fine exactly how it should. However when I print the element `<div class="ui small star rating" data-rating="0" data-max-rating="5">Leave rating</div>` there seems to be a problem with the specific div tag I am trying to print and not the order of what gets printed.

Comment: Then check the last part of my answer, and check your CSS for the classes that div has (ui small star rating) in order to see if they are getting hidden or invisible.

Comment: Checked the CSS there is no `display:none` or anything like that, but I have realized something else, you pointed out that PHP code gets executed before js, in my code just above the ajax function I have this bit of code:  `$(document)
            .ready(function(){
                $('.ui.small.rating').rating('disable');
            });` which initializes the star rating feature. Could there be an issue here with the fact that the PHP is being rendered before the js?